# Scala: Strange MatchError when unapplying tuple with nulls

Tags: scala

Can anybody well-versed in Scala explain why this works:

```
scala> Tuple2[String,String]("w3wre", "werffd")
res0: (String, String) = (w3wre,werffd)

scala> val (s1:Any, s2:Any) = Tuple2[String,String]("w3wre", "werffd")
s1: Any = w3wre
s2: Any = werffd
```

But not this?

```
scala> Tuple2[String,String]("w3wre", null)
res1: (String, String) = (w3wre,null)

scala> val (s1:Any, s2:Any) = Tuple2[String,String]("w3wre", null)
scala.MatchError: (w3wre,null) (of class scala.Tuple2)
    at .<init>(<console>:9)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
...
```

(Clearly Any-type can contain `null`s:

```
scala> val n:Any = null
n: Any = null

scala> val n:Any = null.asInstanceOf[String]
n: Any = null
```

)

?

Comment: A slightly more minimal example: `val (a, b: Any) = ((), null)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language specification *explicitly* says that such type patterns do not match `null` ([8.2 Type Patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns), emphasis mine):

> Type patterns consist of types, type variables, and wildcards. A type pattern *T* is of one of the following forms:
>
> - A reference to a class *C*, *p.C*, or *T#C*. This type pattern matches any **non-null instance** of the given class.

However, I don't know the language designers' reasoning behind not matching `null`.

Comment: Perhaps because it might lead to some counterintuitive results - e.g. `(null: Any) match { case _: String => "string"; case _: Int => "int"; case _ => "other" }` would evaluate to `"string"`.

Comment: Are you sure? I believe a type pattern gets converted to an `instanceof`, and `null instanceof T` always returns `false`

Comment: @Clashsoft That's just an implementation detail. If Scala had different semantics it would compile to different bytecode instructions.